# Creating a TCP Pipeline architecture with ZeroMQ and PHP?

Tags: php, zeromq

After seeing ZeroMQ is the answer (http://vimeo.com/20605470), by Ian Barber, i got excited about testing out the pipeline pattern presented by him. However, he uses an IPC example: https://github.com/ianbarber/ZeroMQ-Talk/tree/master/worker

How this should work with TCP? How can i instantiate workers through TCP instead of process forking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will look almost exactly the same, but instead of using `ipc://` sockets names you would use `tcp://` socket names.  So instead of this:

```
$work->bind("ipc:///tmp/work");
$ctrl->bind("ipc:///tmp/control");
```

You might have this:

```
$work->bind("tcp://*:8080");
$ctrl->bind("tcp://*:8081");
```

This has the `work` socket listening on port `8080` and the `ctrl` socket listening on port `8081`.  Your `connect` operations would look something like:

```
$work->connect("tcp://1.2.3.4:8080");
```

(Assuming the ip address of your server was `1.2.3.4`).

Comment: I was hoping it was obvious from my example that you can specify whatever port you want.  Sorry if that wasn't clear.  I've found that ZMQ has really documentation with lots of examples; you might want to take a look.